# Why dllexport-ing a class with a method also exports the a symbol used by that method, even if it's not dllexport-ed itself?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, visibility, dllexport

[Take a source file like this](https://godbolt.org/z/qjb6Wcacx):

```cpp
namespace detail {
inline int helper() {
    return 1;
}
}

struct __declspec(dllexport) Foo {
    int fun() {
        return 2*detail::helper();
    };
};
```

**Without** `__declspec(dllexport)`, no code is generated, whereas **with it**, here it is:

```
int detail::helper(void) PROC                          ; detail::helper, COMDAT
        mov     eax, 1
        ret     0
int detail::helper(void) ENDP                          ; detail::helper

this$ = 8
int Foo::fun(void) PROC                              ; Foo::fun, COMDAT
        mov     eax, 2
        ret     0
int Foo::fun(void) ENDP                              ; Foo::fun
```

Why is the `helper` symbol in the assembly, considering is not even used by `fun`'s assembly, which inlines the call to `helper`.

Comment: Because it wasn't inlined (probably because optimizations are turned off) and so it needs to be there so Foo::fun can call it?

Comment: @user253751, that doesn't seem to be the case. I'll update the example to show why I think so.

Comment: What if `main` prints the address of `Foo::fun` (just to make sure the code gets generated) but it's not dllexport?

Comment: @user253751, maybe it's because of my lack of knowledge on this topic, but I don't see why what you say implies that `detail::helper` has to be exported too.

Comment: Where do you see that detail::helper is exported?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that it is in the assembly mean that the linker does find it if another object uses it?

Comment: You expect the linker to find it because if two source files both use detail::helper they should use the same copy of detail::helper. That doesn't mean it's dllexported.

Comment: Even so, without `dllexport` at all, neither function is in the assembly. With `dllexport` on `Fun` both `Foo::fun` and `detail::helper` are in the assembly, even though the code for `Foo::fun` has no reference to `detail::helper`. Then why does `dllexport` on `Fun` have the effect of making `detail::helper` appear in the assembly?

Comment: Try putting `helper` into an anonymous namespace. ie change `namespace detail {` to `namespace {`

Comment: @RichardCritten, I get the [same assembly, except that ``s/detail/`anonymous namespace'/g``](https://godbolt.org/z/7Pcj8eGMa).